# CentOS 7, Integrating SAMBA server with LDAP server to authenticate users through LDAP

Tags: centos7, ldap, samba, certificate

I spent many hours trying to solve my problem, but unfortunately to no avail.
Im configuring SAMBA server on CentOS 7. I want to fetch users' credentials from LDAP server, so they will be able to authenticate to SAMBA using their LDAP credentials.
SAMBA server must authenticate to LDAP server via a specific user and credentials stored in "secrets.tdb" file. However, I want to authenticate to LDAP server using *.pem certificate. Is its possible?
Only information that i have is:

- TLS Certificate (cert.pem)
- ou=Users
- o=COMPANY
- ldap server name: ldaps://ldapserv.servers.company.net

I have no other information about LDAP server.
Is it possible to successfully authenticate SAMBA server to LDAP server using the aforementioned data?
Thanks in advance.